# Gvim on Windows: file marks reset after opening with administrator rights

Tags: windows, vim

If I set a file mark using `mD` it will work fine, even after closing Gvim and opening it back up. However, if I was previously using Gvim without windows administrator rights then open it up **with** admin rights, the marks don't work any more. The same thing happens in reverse. Essentially, whenever I swap from using gvim with admin rights to using it without, my file marks no longer work.

`viminfo: '100,<50,s10,h,rA:,rB:,f1`

Comment: Did you mean `mD`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. What version of gvim do you have? Any plugins? Can you check the viminfo file "$HOME/_viminfo" if it contains marks after editing session with admin rights and without them?